# Django Many To Many Field Causing Me Grief

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to list players who may belong to multiple teams.  I set up my code for users to be able to select multiple teams, and that is working fine.  However, now that I have done this, the automatic population of fields is no longer working.  It worked fine with a foreign key but once I changed the model field reference to ManyToManyField, the auto population of the dropdown fields I set up no longer works.  Please help!  I'm a newbie, so if there's a better way to go about what I'm trying to accomplish I'm open to other thoughts.  Here is my code:

```
Models.Py

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    users = User.objects.select_related('userprofile').all()        
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team,related_name='teamprofile')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.get_full_name()

class Team(models.Model):
    team = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["team"]

    def __str__(self):
       return self.team

Views.Py

def view_byteam(request):
    form = ViewByTeam(request.user, request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            department = form.cleaned_data['dropdown']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(team.get_absolute_url1())
    return render(request,'/view_byteam.html',{'form':form})

Forms.py

class ViewByTeam(forms.Form):

    dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, user,*args, **kwargs):
    super(ViewByTeam, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = Team.objects.filter(team=user.userprofile.team)
        self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = qs
        self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
        self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
```

The above works with a foreignkey field reference on team but when I change it to ManyToMany, the field is now blank.  I've already tried to change user.userprofile.team to user.userprofile.team.all() and to user.userprofile.team.all and continue to receive error messages that I can't decipher.  The code above returns nothing, I still get the form but the dropdown is blank.  It's as if the code can no longer decipher the team of the user from their profile.  I've checked in other places and the system is taking the team value, but not able to use it in this section of my code for some reason.  I'm trying to get it to return multiple values, minimally at least one but it should be able to return multiple values.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the original question of what to change after changing field from foreignkey to manytomany was to update my filter from qs = Team.objects.filter(user.userprofile.team) to qs = Team.objects.filter(team__in=user.userprofile.team.all()).

Answer (score 1):

Change this line in form.**init**() method,

```
qs = Team.objects.filter(team__in=user.userprofile.team.all())
```

After you've changed the field to `ManyToMany` relation, the attribute is a list of objects. Change your filter accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Unfortunately when I tried that I received the following error message....'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable.  Any ideas on that?  I again tried to add .all and the () at the end of the user.userprofile.team but it still didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: After fooling around a bit, I found that the following line of code solved my problem:  qs = Team.objects.filter(team__in=user.userprofile.team.all())  Thank you so much for your input!!!!!!